# How To Best Access Objects/Variables Outside of a Closure?

Tags: javascript, jquery, object, closures

The following is a sample of code (extracted only the necessary section) that I intend to use to combine several thumbnails that are ready (downloaded) and then insert them into the DOM a certain way. JSLint passes this code as OK but FF/Firebug fails it at this section below where I get an error saying "TypeError: readyHTML is null". I have even tried to declare `this.readyHTML = new ReadyHTML();` and `var self = this;` and then reference it as `self.readyHTML` from the `img.onload = function () {};` closure. Basically I need to be able to access and update the readyHTML object from within the closure of img.onload. Isn't it possible? I think am doing something wrong but I cannot figure out where/how/why.

```
   function ReadyHTML() {
    "use strict";
    this.buffer = [];
    ReadyHTML.prototype.append = function (string) {
        this.buffer.push(string);
        return this;
    };
    return true;
}

function f() {
    "use strict";
    var readyHTML = new ReadyHTML();
    var img = new Image();
    var image_url;
    img.onload = function () {
        readyHTML.append('<a href=""><img src="' + image_url + '" class="xph4 ca"/></a>');
    };
    image_url = "some/url/to/an/image";
    img.src = image_url; // This calls img.onload whence the error comes
}
```

Comment: [I get no errors in Firefox](http://jsfiddle.net/bHRas/1). However, returning `true` from a constructor doesn't make much sense (it's just ignored).

Comment: bfavaretto thanks for pointing out 'return' oversight. I've checked your code, but I think you never got to call the img.onload since you must assign img.src some image url, then you will see the error.

Comment: I still don't get an error even after setting the src (link above updated).

Comment: @EdNdee still there is no error http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/ve222/2/

Comment: Thanks all. Still I have the error myself. I've gotta see what/where the issue is then.

Comment: try using this.prototype instead of readyHTML.prototype

Comment: uptownhr I get an error still "TypeError: this.prototype is undefined". IMHO I think we need to point to the prototype of the correct type that we seek to extend i.e. ReadyHTML (not even readyHTML which is only an instance of ReadyHTML) instead of this.prototype which is ambiguous.